Lilypond scaling a score with many parts to avoid over-full pages
I'm trying to typeset a larger piece than I normally do.  It has 44 instruments, which I've condensed into 35 staves using a lot of \partCombine.
I've tried to put this onto A3 paper:
$(set-default-paper-size "a3") 

And I've tried to remove empty staves where possible with:
\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \RemoveEmptyStaves
  }
}

The first page, which shows all staves (of which most are empty) has some issues with overlapping:
Drawing systems...
warning: compressing over-full page by 69.7 staff-spaces
warning: page 1 has been compressed

Busy pages get much worse to the point where I can't tell the difference between a tenor and alto clef.
warning: compressing over-full page by 123.7 staff-spaces
warning: page 18 has been compressed


If I go to A2 paper, things get so much better, but there are still a few over-full pages with minor collisions.

A1 resolves all collisions, but the printing cost is going to be incredible, and turning half-square-meter pages during a performance is going to look a little silly.
I notice that a single note is the same size on all paper sizes.  Is there a way for me to globally scale everything down (staves, text, note heads) so I can use A3?  If not, is there a better solution?

Obviously setting the staff size is the correct approach, but creating A1 or A2 output would not be a major issue: not only printing by adapting to a given page size will work, but, in case you use PDF (or PostScript based printing), scaling to a desired page size is immediate and always consistent, and can be achieved with simple command line tools like ghostscript.

Set the staff size of the score by doing
#(set-global-staff-size the-staff-size)

where the-staff-size is the height of one standard staff in pt (default is 20pt). See the manual for details:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/setting-the-staff-size

Perfect!  #(set-global-staff-size 12) was the largest I could manage without compressed pages.
